# C program which is finding "happy" nums recursively

Tags: c, recursion

Hello guys i am trying to implement a program which is finding the **happy** numbers were between two numbers A and B.

Summing the squares of all the digits of the number, we replace the number with the outcome, and repeat the process. If after some steps the result is equal to 1 (and stay there), then we say that the number N is `**<happy>**`. Conversely, if the process is repeated indefinitely without ever showing the number 1, then we say that the number N is `**<sad>**`.

*For example, the number 7 is happy because the procedure described above leads to the following steps: 7, 49, 97, 130, 10, 1, 1, 1 ... Conversely, the number 42 is sad because the process leads to a infinite sequence 42, 20, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, 37 ...*

I try this right down but i am getting either segm faults or no results.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void happy( char * A, int n);
int numPlaces (long n);

int main(void)
{
    long A,B;
    int npA;
    char *Ap;
    printf("Give 2 Numbers\n");
    scanf("%li %li",&A,&B);
    npA = numPlaces(A);
    Ap = malloc(npA);
    printf("%ld %d\n",A,npA);
    //Search for happy numbers from A to B
    do{
        sprintf(Ap, "%ld", A);
        happy(Ap,npA);
        A++;
        if ( npA < numPlaces(A) )
        {
            npA++;
            Ap = realloc(Ap, npA);
        }

    }while( A <= B);




}
//Finds happy numbers
void happy( char * A, int n)
    {   
        //Basic Condition
        if ( n == 1)
        {
            if (A[0] == 1 || A[0] == 7)
            printf("%c\n",A[0]);
            printf("%s\n",A);
            return;
        }
        long sum = 0 ;
        char * sumA;
        int nsum;
        int Ai;
        //Sum the squares of the current number
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
        {
            Ai = atoi(&A[i]);
            sum = sum +  (Ai*Ai);
        }
        nsum = numPlaces (sum);
        sumA = malloc(nsum);
        sprintf(sumA, "%li", sum);
        happy(sumA,nsum);
        free(sumA);
    }

//Count digits of a number 
int numPlaces (long n) 
    {
        if (n < 0) return 0;
        if (n < 10) return 1;
        return 1 + numPlaces (n / 10);
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try to step through using a debugger?

Comment: How do you plan to have your program return results for "sad" numbers, where the calculations repeat indefinitely?  Have you really thought this through?

Comment: Yes and it helps me to find a lot of bugs but nothing further...

Comment: @Spyreto "Sad Number" will eventually overflow either the heap/stack. that's why you are getting the error. the program cannot go forever.

Comment: Then use it to fix those *lot of bugs* until it shows you the problem.

Comment: The returning right now is for testing i am focusing  on functionality. I don't think that the calculations repeat indefinitely but I will check the mathematically background of the basic condition in happy faction

Comment: @Spyreto What is the point of a program which only works with already-known solutions?  At that point, it's essentially a table lookup for those solutions, and a gamble for anything else.

Comment: @pjs  you have right I didn't  approached it enough before I post it. I will look into  better. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution tested and working..
Thanks for your time and I am sorry for my vagueness.
Every advice about this solution would be welcome

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void happy( char * A, int n);
int numPlaces (long n);
int happynum = 0;
int main(void)
{
    long A,B;
    int npA;
    char *Ap;
    printf("Give 2 Numbers\n");
    scanf("%li %li",&A,&B);
    npA = numPlaces(A);
    Ap = malloc(npA);
    //Search for happy numbers from A to B
    do{
        sprintf(Ap, "%ld", A);
        happy(Ap,npA);
        if (happynum ==1)
        printf("%s\n",Ap);
        A++;
        if ( npA < numPlaces(A) )
        {
            npA++;
            Ap = realloc(Ap, npA);
        }

    }while( A <= B);




}
//Finds happy numbers
void happy( char * A, int n)
    {   
        //Basic Condition
        if ( n == 1)
        {
            if (A[0] == '3' || A[0] == '6' || A[0] == '9')
            {
                happynum = 0;
            }    
            else
            {
                happynum = 1;
            }
            return;
        }
        long sum = 0;
        char * sumA;
        int nsum;
        int Ai;
        //Sum the squares of the current number
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
        {
            Ai = (int)(A[i]-48);
            sum = sum +  (Ai*Ai);
        }
        nsum = numPlaces (sum);
        sumA = malloc(nsum);
        sprintf(sumA, "%li", sum);
        happy(sumA,nsum);
        free(sumA);
    }

//Count digits of a number 
int numPlaces (long n) 
    {
        if (n < 0) return 0;
        if (n < 10) return 1;
        return 1 + numPlaces (n / 10);
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm. This will mark (nearly) any number with two or more digits as happy. The single-digit happy numbers are 1 and 7; I'm not sure why you test for 3, 6 and 9.

Comment: Other points: Your function `happy` should return an integer that indicates whether a number is happy or not instead of storing that information in a global value. I've said in my answer that you shouldn't allocate with `malloc` in the first place, but if you must allocate, dont allocate based on `A` and re-allocate; allocate based on the highest number `B` from the start.

Answer (score 1):

by the definition of your program sad numbers will cause your program to run forever

> Conversely, if the process is repeated indefinitely

You need to add a stopping condition, like if I have looped for 1000 times, or if you hit a well known non terminating number (like 4) (is there a definite list of these? I dont know)

Comment: You're right, in my attempt to do it more efficiently(because tis is the main object of the problem 10s runtime and 256mb memory limit ) I did not think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses some questionable practices. Yoe may be misguided because you are concerned about performance and memory usage.

- When you allocate memory for the string, you forget to allocate one character for the null terminator. But you shouldn't be allocating, re-allocating and freeing constantly anyway. Dynamic memory allocation is expensive compared to your other operations.

  Your limits are `long`, which may be a 32-bit or 64-bit signed integer, depending on your platform. The maximum number that can be represented with e 64-bit signed integer is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This is a number with 19 digits. Add one for the null terminator and one for a possible minus sign, so that overflow won't hurt, you and use a buffer of 21 chars on the stack.
- You probably shouldn't be using strings inthe first place. Use the basic code to extract the digits: Split off the digit by taking the remainder of a division by 10. Then divide by 10 until you get zero. (And if you use strings with a fixed buffer size, as described above, you don't have to calculate the difits separately: `sprintf` returns the number of characters written to the string.
- Your functions shouldn't be recursive. A loop is enough. As pm100 has noted, you need a termination criterion: You must keep track of the numbers that you have already visited. Each recursive call creates a new state; it is easier to keep an array, that can be repeatedly looked at in a loop. When you see a number that you have already seen (other than 1, of course), your number is sad.

Happy and sad numbers have this property that when your sum of squares is a number with a known happiness, the original number has this happiness, too. If you visit a known das number, the original number is sad. If you visit a known happy number, the original number is happy.

The limits of your ranges may ba large, but the sum of square digits is not large; it can be at most the number of digits times 81. In particular:

```
    type                   max. number    number of max. square sum       dss

    int                  2,147,483,647                1,999,999,999       730
    uint                 4,294,967,295                3,999,999,999       738
    long     9,223,372,036,854,775,807    8,999,999,999,999,999,999      1522
    ulong   18,446,744,073,709,55,1616    9,999,999,999,999,999,999      1539
```

That means that when you take the sum of digit squares of an unsigned long, you will get a number that is smaller than 1540. Create an array of 1540 entries and mark all known happy numbers with 1. Then you can reduce your problem to taking the sum of digit squares once and then looking up the happiness of the number in this array.

(You can do the precalculation of the array once when you start the program.)

Comment: I am self-taught  ( just for hobby ), anyway I find your advices very helpful! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: That's okay; programming is a nice hobby. But the compiler doesn't care whether you're a hobbyist or a professional. `:)`